# How to make the width of items 100%, 50% or 33% depending on quantity

Tags: html, css

I have a container that sometimes has two items or three or one. If there is one item, I want each container (there is only one) to have a width of 100%. If there are two items, I want each container to have a width of 50%. If there are three items, I want each container to have a width of 33%. The number of items is not known before hand but after a script executes. How can I accomplish the above in css?

Comment: In your script you can easily compute the needed percentage then either affect the appropriate class to each item, assumed you've already include these classes in your CSS definitions. Please show us current script and HTML code to get a more detailed answer.

Comment: As mentioned above, a server-side script can generate the classes depending on the number of items. You can also use JavaScript to count the number of items and based on that apply a CSS class

Answer (score 5):

Behold, the power of `flex: 1`.

- Five variations of the same container
- Each container with increasing number of divs (from 1 - 5).
- Pure CSS (flexbox), and one set of style rules for all
- No need to define any widths or percentages

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;             /* center containers on page */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 75%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;                 /* non-essential decorative styles */
    background-color: yellow;            /* non-essential decorative styles */
    border: 1px solid black;             /* non-essential decorative styles */
}

.box {
    flex: 1;                             /* THE KEY RULE */
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;                         /* non-essential decorative styles */
    background-color: lightgreen;        /* non-essential decorative styles */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

The width of each green box is based on the available space in the container. However, if you want each box to have a *minimum size* you could adjust the `flex` rule to something like `flex: 1 0 75px`. This means the boxes will expand as much as possible, but will never be less than 75px wide.

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

Comment: My god, Flex is really great. Question: if the widths are spread equally, why do you need to set `width:75px;` ?

Comment: So it looks nice... Its 75%, not px

Comment: @Aziz, I forgot to delete that. You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this effect by using pairs of `:nth-of-type` and `:nth-last-of-type` pseudo-classes.

```
li:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(1) {
width: 100%;
}

li:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(2),
li:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(1) {
width: 50%;
}

li:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(3),
li:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(2),
li:nth-of-type(3):nth-last-of-type(1) {
width: 33.33%;
}
```

**Complete Example:**

```css
ol {
display: block;
height: 40px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

li {
display:inline-block;
margin: 2px 0;
padding: 0;
height: 36px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(127,127,127);
font-weight:bold;
}

li:nth-of-type(1) {
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

li:nth-of-type(2) {
background-color: rgb(63,225,63);
}

li:nth-of-type(3) {
background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
}

li:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(1) {
width: 100%;
}

li:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(2),
li:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(1) {
width: 50%;
}

li:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(3),
li:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(2),
li:nth-of-type(3):nth-last-of-type(1) {
width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<ol><li>100% Item</li></ol>

<ol><li>50% Item</li><li>50% Item</li></ol>

<ol><li>33% Item</li><li>33% Item</li><li>33% Item</li></ol>
```

Comment: What's the browser support for this? interesting approach

Comment: Complete browser support from IE9 onwards. See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3